# Power BI: Total no. of records (S.No) get aggregated on performing union of CSV

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have 40-50 csv files for different cities. I would want to show the n**umber of records** across time filtered by city and hashtag.

1. The 'S.No' got aggregated and is showing the sum of records (I dont understand why did it shows the sum, shouldnt it be individual record numbers when performing Union?) i.e. Even if individual files have S.No from 1-50, the final table should show S.No from 1-2500. but that is not the case here.

**Below image shows the data in query editor.**

[image]

**This image shows the table with aggregated sums in 'Data table view'**
[image]

As we see, the **S.No** is shown  aggregated.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Pasting the query from Advance Editor:

```
let
    Source = Folder.Files("C:\Users\Desktop\data collection\twitter_new_count"),
    #"Filtered Hidden Files1" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),
    #"Invoke Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Hidden Files1", "Transform File from twitter_new_count", each #"Transform File from twitter_new_count"([Content])),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Invoke Custom Function1", {"Name", "Source.Name"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Renamed Columns1", {"Source.Name", "Transform File from twitter_new_count"}),
    #"Expanded Table Column1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Transform File from twitter_new_count", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transform File from twitter_new_count"(#"Sample File"))),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Table Column1",{{"Source.Name", type text}, {"", Int64.Type}, {"ttext", type text}, {"date", type datetime}, {"isretweet", type logical}, {"retweetcount", Int64.Type}, {"favoritecount", Int64.Type}, {"score", Int64.Type}, {"term", type text}, {"city", type text}, {"country", type text}, {"duplicate", type logical}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each true),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{{"", "S.No"}}),
    #"Inserted Date" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Date.1", each DateTime.Date([date]), type date),
    #"Inserted Time" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Date", "Time", each DateTime.Time([date]), type time),
    #"Renamed Columns2" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Inserted Time",{{"date", "Datentime"}, {"Date.1", "Date"}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Renamed Columns2", "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Index",{"Index"}),
    #"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Index", 1, 1),
    #"Renamed Columns3" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Added Index1",{{"Index", "Row Number"}}),
    #"Inserted Hour" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns3", "Hour", each Time.Hour([Datentime]), Int64.Type),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Inserted Hour", each true),
    #"Renamed Columns4" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{{"Hour", "Hour of Day"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns4
```

Comment: How are you performing a union?

Comment: Just a join of all CSV s when I import them

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what process you mean by "join". Are you loading them all from a folder or manually appending them all together or something else?

Comment: Manually appending from folder. Yes .

Comment: Can you paste the M code from the Advanced Editor into your question?

Comment: @AlexisOlson Have edited the question with the query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure those `S.No` values in the data table view are *not* aggregated, but rather they are just sorted differently than in the query editor view. Check the total number of rows to be sure.